# Is there a way to tell if an input stream is opened and not closed anywhere in the code

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I work in Java, and my IDE is Intellij.
I had production issues with being unable to delete files that were read (opened) but not closed properly, simply because not all branches in code led to fileInputStream.close().

I was wandering if there is a way for intelij IDEA to go over all my code and tell if there are InputStreams (FileInputStream for example) that are opened and does not have a close() method call.

It would make my bug fix much better.

Comment: if your open and close code is not in the same method, it would be impossible to follow every code path (there may be an infinite number of combinations).  as a general rule, close all your resources in finally blocks in order to avoid these types of resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use QAPlug-FindBugs plugin,it will be able to detect unclosed stream:

You can install the plugin using IDEA Plugin Manager. Go to settings and then search for plugins. Then install QAPlug and QAPlug-FindBugs both from JetBrains Plugin. Restart IDE and right click on your project and select analyze code.Then if you have unclosed stream it will report.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: We had an unclosed stream in our code that findbugs didn't find.  BTW, I really like findbugs and think it is a great tool, but it did miss that open stream.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to java 7, where FileInputStreams are autoclosable.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-new-feature-%E2%80%93

Comment: This require code changes.  Perhaps even substantial ones.  That may not always be an option.